# Android background sizes - resizing to fit all devices

Tags: android

this is a slightly different question to other background image sizing questions asked before. On this fragment when the user selects an icon the background image changes dynamically on each click. For example if the user clicks an icon of the sun the background will change to a sunny one, if they click a cloud icon the background will change to cloudy and so on.

I use a simple switch statement to achieve this:

```
@Override
public void onMoodClick(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            moodBefore = 1;
            backgroundChanger.setImageResource(R.mipmap.background_clouds_excited);
            hasSelected = true;
            break;

        case 1:
            moodBefore = 2;
            backgroundChanger.setImageResource(R.mipmap.background_clouds_happy);
            hasSelected = true;
            break;
```

The problem is: it looks perfect on the emulator which is set up as a pixel 2. However when I load the app onto my Galaxy s10 I notice that part of the background is getting chopped off. So like only half the sun is visible on my s10 but the full background is visible on the pixel 2 emulator. Would anyone know a potential fix for this issue so the backgrounds are a little more dynamic and can accommodate different screen sizes?

LAYOUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/FragmentWorkoutMood2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.fragments.WorkoutFragment">

<com.example.feelingfit.utils.CropImageView
    android:id="@+id/workoutBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:src="@mipmap/background_clouds_workout_default"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: use a constraint layout to maintain aspect ratios regardless of screen sizes

Comment: I use a constraint layout on all my activities and fragments by default but this has no bearing on the issue.

Comment: Could you post your layout please so as to see how these views are being constrained?

Comment: Updated my question to include the relevant section of the xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `android:scaleType` on your xml file for `backgroundChanger` element. You check the this link, you will see the images for each scaletype. You can select the best for you.
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide